# Setting environment path for emacs for running scala with ensime

Tags: scala, github, emacs, ensime

I was trying to run ensime for emacs. Here is the the init.el - https://github.com/michaelpnash/emacs-for-scala/blob/master/.emacs.d/init.el

Before [the require ensime line](https://github.com/michaelpnash/emacs-for-scala/blob/master/.emacs.d/init.el#L25) I add the Path for sbt and scala.

```
(setenv "PATH" (concat "/usr/local/bin/scala:" (getenv "PATH")))
(setenv "PATH" (concat "/usr/local/bin/sbt:" (getenv "PATH")))



$ which sbt
/usr/local/bin/sbt
$ which scala
/usr/local/bin/scala
```

In ~/.sbt/plugins.sbt I have the following snippet -

```
resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("snapshots")

addSbtPlugin("org.ensime" % "ensime-sbt" % "0.1.6")
```

I clone a sample boilerplate - git clone git://github.com/dph01/scala-sbt-template.git

and then sbt "ensime generate"

It runs well, but while I open emacs it gives me an error -

```
check that set is on your PATH and that your config is compatible with github.com/ensime/ensime-server/wiki/Example-Configuration-File [(error Error reading configuration file, : (end-of-file))]
```

Comment: FYI, use `ensime-sbt` version `0.2.0`.

Answer (score 1):

you're using an ancient version of `ensime-sbt`. Start again by installing it following these instructions https://github.com/ensime/ensime-sbt

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your `init.el` (after calling package-initialize):

```
(when (memq window-system '(mac ns)) 
  (exec-path-from-shell-initialize))
```

You may want to remove the check for mac if you want to load the path from shell always.

https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell

Also see:

https://github.com/ensime/ensime-emacs/issues/225

https://github.com/ensime/ensime-server/issues/670